# Anime Character Normals break after armature

Tags: rigging, armature, normals

I am trying to model an anime styled character for my game and after rigging, the normal breaks. I can deactivate the armature and the shading works fine but I need the armature.

I have tried using Topology Proxies, Smooth Proxies, Smoothing vectors and nothing works. As for the topology, I am aware it's not clean, I have been doing Blender for only 6 months and I've made it this far therefore I do not want to restart. I am using Rigify.

Here are the two problems that need fixing the most

[image]

[image]

Apologies for the vagueness of the question, it's hard to be specific with the problem I'm facing, all I know is that the Rig breaks the Normals.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIueZ7jE14Ljrn9bkInbilwngM_BG-Ew/view?usp=sharing)